# Codeigniter multiple language cause facebook share error why?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, share

I have a project with multiple language when I try to share it on facebook I got this error.

File: path/Language.php: 15 function:_error_handler.

```
 function switch_lang($language = "") {
        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);
        setcookie('site_lang', $language, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); 
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);//This is Line 15
       //When I remove the redirect above it work.

    }
```

And this is how the switch_language function get call.

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="javascript:window.location.href='<?php echo base_url(); ?>language/switch_lang/'+this.value;">
      <option value="korean" <?php if($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'korean') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> > 한국어 </option>
      <option value="chinese" <?php if($this->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'chinese') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> > 中文 </option>             
 </select>
```

Comment: `redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` - who writes code this terrible? Someone who does not have the slightest idea how unreliable the HTTP referrer is …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sovel the problem by using javascript history.back function instead of php redirect

```
echo '<script> window.history.back();</script>';
```